# Order objects in window with core-animation

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-animation

I have SegmentedController and box. i use core animation layer (View Effects Inspector) for change color user interface and set shadow for some objects...Sometimes when i build and ran my app i have a trouble like this

[image]

How i may fix order SegmentedController and Box?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you try to reinvent the wheel? Use NSTabView: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TabView/Concepts/HowTabViewsWork.html

Comment: I new in cocoa and don't now how to change tipe of segmentedcontroll for TabView. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

**My answer on my question:** to change tipe of segmentedcontroll for TabViev use TabView with stile Tabless... and use SegmentedControll with Stile which you need. For switching tab use cocoa bindings...for setup order of objects in window choose menu item Editor-Arrangement...